# Javascript smooth scroll with scroll-margin-top creates a jump at the end

Tags: javascript, css, smooth-scrolling

I'm implementing smooth scrolling on my website using *JavaScript*, and I've encountered an issue with *CSS* **scroll-margin-top** causing a jump at the end. I'm using the following CSS for scroll margins:

```
class or div {
  scroll-margin-top: 6rem;/*any size*/
}
```

I have a smooth scroll JavaScript function as well. The problem is that when scrolling to these sections, there's a noticeable jump when reaching the end of the scroll.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
    var ssSmoothScroll = function () {
      $('a[href^="#"], area[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        var target = $($(this).attr('href'));
        if (target.length) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
          }, cfg.scrollDuration, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target.attr('id');
          });
        }
      });
    };
```

How can I resolve this issue and maintain smooth scrolling without the jump at the end?

[The JsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6fe1xpk0/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `scroll-margin-top` value for the target element and subtracts it from the scrolling destination.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a[href^="#"], area[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
    var target = $($(this).attr('href'));
    if (target.length) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var scrollMargin = target.css('scroll-margin-top'); // Get scroll-margin-top value
      var offset = scrollMargin ? parseInt(scrollMargin) : 0; // Parse the value
      $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top - offset // Consider scroll-margin-top
      }, 1000, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target.attr('id');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
 body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    #first,
    #second,
    #third,
    #fourth,
    #fifth {
      scroll-margin-top: 6rem;
    }

    /* Additional styles for demonstration purposes */
    section {
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      font-size: 2rem;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
 <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#first">first</a></li>
      <li><a href="#second">second</a></li>
      <li><a href="#third">third</a></li>
      <li><a href="#fourth">fourth</a></li>
      <li><a href="#fifth">fifth</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <section id="first">first</section>
  <section id="second">second</section>
  <section id="third">third</section>
  <section id="fourth">fourth</section>
  <section id="fifth">fifth</section>
```